# Homeomorphism: sphere with andipodal points removed

Tags: geometry, algebraic-topology

Consider the sphere $S^2 \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ with $2n$ points removed. We'll have the set $S^{2} \setminus \{ z_{1}, \ldots,  z_{2n}\}$. Is this set homeomorphic to the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ with $2n-1$ points removed? I'm not being able to visualize a good projection. Any tips?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need the antipodality condition. Use the stereographic projection from one of the removed points. Or consider that if $X\cong Y$ then $X\setminus\{x\}\cong Y\setminus\{f(x)\}$ where $f$ is an omeomorphism from $X$ to $Y$. Apply this fact to the sphere minus one of the removed points.